# Efficient hard data sampling for triplet loss

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am trying to implement a deep network for triplet loss in Caffe.
When I select three samples for anchor, positive, negative images randomly, it almost produces zero losses. So I tried the following strategy:

```
If I have 15,000 training images,
1. extract features of 15,000 images with the current weights.
2. calculate the triplet losses with all possible triplet combinations.
3. use the hard samples with n largest losses, and update the network n times.
4. iterate the above steps every k iterations to get new hard samples.
```

The step 1 is fast, but I think step 2 is very time-consuming and is really inefficient. So, I wonder whether there are other efficient strategies for hard data sampling.

Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the paper describing the triplet loss had a negative mining method - you should check it out. Have you considered using [Wexler at al. multibatch loss](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07270)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, if your dataset is large, it is infeasible to sample hard triplet from the whole dataset. In fact, you can choose hard triplet for only a small proportion of your training dataset, which will be much more time-saving. After training the network using the hard triplet generated for K iterations. You feed the network with the next batch of images from the dataset and generate the new hard triplet.

In this way, the computation cost is acceptable and network is gradually improving as the training process goes.

see the [article here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.01325.pdf) for more reference.(section 5.1)